# Using MySQL in Wookmark and creating arrays from a database

Tags: php, mysqli

I use the Wookmark plugin and want to be able to use my database to output content. The current format is in PHP arrays and is as following:

```
$data = array(
  array(
    'id' => "1",
    'title' => "First image",
    'url' => "http://www.example.org/1",
    'width' => "560",
    'height' => "560",
    'image' => "",
    'preview' => ""
  ),
  array(
    'id' => "2",
    'title' => "Second image",
    'url' => "http://www.example.org/1",
    'width' => "560",
    'height' => "560",
    'image' => "",
    'preview' => ""
  )
);
```

I've tried and testet with some code, but don't really have much experience on the field. I tried to search around on Stackoverflow without success. Anyway, this i what i tried using MySQLI (however it can be completely wrong.)

```
$sth = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from entries");
$column = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)){
    $column[] = $row[$key];
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to store data in your database that is currently stored as PHP arrays? Do you already have data in the database and want to display it via HTML? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can save image data in your MySQL database and show them on a HTML page in `Wookmark` style using the Wookmark-jQuery plugin. A sample database can be built by downloading JSON data using Wookmark JSON API.

### Importing to Database

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    referer VARCHAR(255),
    url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    width SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    height SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    image VARCHAR(255),
    preview VARCHAR(255)
);
```

A quick PHP script to download and import image data from Wookmark

```
<?PHP
//### Import Wookmark's popular images to database ###//
$imgs = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.wookmark.com/api/json/popular'), true);

$SQL = "INSERT INTO images VALUES(:id, :title, :referer, :url, :width, :height, :image, :preview)";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=imgbase", "username", "password");
$stmnt = $db->prepare($SQL);

foreach($imgs as $img){
    $stmnt->execute($img);
}

exit("Done!");
?>
```

### Returning JSON data from database

This simple PHP script can be used to return JSON data from your database table

`popular.php`

```
<?PHP
$per_page = 10;
$page = 1;

if(isset($_GET['per_page'])){
    $per_page = (int) $_GET['per_page'];
    if($per_page < 10) $per_page = 10;
    if($per_page > 50) $per_page = 50;
}

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
    if($page < 1) $page = 1;
}

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM images LIMIT ".(($page-1)*$per_page).",".$per_page;
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=imgbase", "username", "password");
$imgdata = "(".json_encode($db->query($SQL)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)).")";
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo isset($_GET['callback'])?$_GET['callback'].$imgdata:$imgdata;
?>
```

### Showing Images in Wookmark style

Use the [Wookmark-jQuery plugin](https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery/). For this example, apart from `jQuery`, only the following files are needed:

- css/main.css
- libs/jquery.imagesloaded.js
- jquery.wookmark.min.js
- example-api/index.html

Edit the `example-api/index.html` file to change the **`apiURL`** from `http://www.wookmark.com/api/json/popular` to the URL of your `popular.php` page.

When you then navigate to the index.html, you will see images arranged in the same style as wookmark.com